# I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with getDay()

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I wanted the page to detect if it was Thursday, and if it was display some text. I don't understand why this won't work. Is it because I can do = on a if than? Please explain, thank you!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="bleh"></p>

    <script>
    var day;
    switch (new Date().getDay()) {
        case 0:
            day = "Sunday";
            break;
        case 1:
            day = "Monday";
            break;
        case 2:
            day = "Tuesday";
            break;
        case 3:
            day = "Wednesday";
            break;
        case 4:
            day = "Thursday";
            break;
        case 5:
            day = "Friday";
            break;
        case  6:
            day = "Saturday";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Today is " + day;
    </script>

   <p id="bleh"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    if(new Date().getDay() == 4)
        document.getElementById("bleh").innerHTML = "Check your grades.";
    }
}
</script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

The part thats not working is this one:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    if(new Date().getDay() == 4)
        document.getElementById("bleh").innerHTML = "Check your grades.";
    }
}
</script>
```

P.S. I would use OnTime, but I am host my webpage off of github pages so I can't load it on there, this is why I'm working with this type of JS.

Comment: "This won't work" what doesnt work?

Comment: And change `case 6:` to `default:` since it must be 6 if you've checked every other possibility. Also, you need a `break` in all cases, even the last one and the default one.

Comment: Inside `if` statement, update code with `if(new Date().getDay() == 4)`, or store the day number in some variable, as you have done for day name inside switch statement. Also invoke the function `myFunction()` for Thursday specific functinality

Comment: `if (day = 4;)` A single `=` is assignment, not comparison and you don't need the `;` in there at all.

Comment: You have duplicate ids.

Comment: Pick your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (day = 4;) {
```

Notice the single `=` where you should be using `==` or `===`. Also remove the semicolon:

```
if (day === 4) {
```

*Also*, as pointed out in the comments, you should be checking the day as a string, since that's what you set it to!

```
if (day === "Thursday") {
```

Comment: If you observe the code of user, you will see the `day` variable contains day name, not day index. So, this answer should instruct for same too.

Answer (score 0):

would not it be better to store your day names in an array like this

```
var days = [
  'Sunday',
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday'
];

function getCurrentDayName (dayIndex) {
  return days[dayIndex];
}

console.log(getCurrentDayName (new Date ().getDay()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of day much easier like this:

```js
let today = new Date()

demo.innerHTML = 
  `Today is 
  ${new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {weekday: 'long'})
  .format(today)}`;

let toDay = today.getDay()

bleh.innerHTML =
  toDay === 4 ?
  'Check your grades.' :
  `Not Thursday. Come back in 
  ${(11 - toDay) % 7} 
  days to re-check.`
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="bleh"></p>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you. My only issue is that it says "Come back in 11 days to re-check.", and I want it to be in a weekly cycle (7 days).

Comment: Please re-check. I haven't invested too much thought into that part of calculation, I gotta admit. You might want to double-check that formula by yourself.